# Display tag related to entry in current locale

Tags: localization, tag

I've got this code snippet I'm working with and I can't get tags pulled out for related entry in current locale.

Maybe worth to mention, that tags is matrix field.

```
  {% set entries = craft.entries %}

  {% for entry in entries %}
  <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
  {% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo({
          sourceElement: entries,
          sourceLocale: craft.locale
  }) %}
     <li>
     { tag.title }}
     </li>
     {% else %}
     <li>
     No tags found
     </li>
     {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why do you define the locale? Isn't this default behaviour?

Comment: At [link](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) under paragraph 'Getting more serious', it says, that 'you can set the 'sourceLocale' if you want to limit the scope to relations created from a particular field.'

Comment: Domini, could you please try posting your code snippets properly indented / formatted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to your question, there's no need
to specify the locale with your `relatedTo` parameter.

I already wrote you in response to your other question, Craft always works in one locale
only if you don't explicitly make it to do otherwise.

```
{% for entry in entries %}

    <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>

    {% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(entry) %}

        {{ loop.first ? '<ul>' }}
        <li>{{ tag.title }}</li>
        {{ loop.last ? '</ul>' }}

    {% else %}

        <p>No tags found</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've used this code before, it worked until I've added first locale.

Comment: Can't have anything to do with adding a locale. You probably must have changed something else.

Comment: For sure. I'm on it now and I'm starting to discover, that It might cause the matrix field. I had tags in Assets field before I think. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I can't follow, Dominic. What matrix and or assets fields are you talking about? Please feel free to add a new question,  *"Display tag related to entry in current locale"* has nothing to do with all this and is answered in my opinion.